# Solving system of equations, Gaussian Elimination

Tags: systems-of-equations, gaussian-elimination

I am hoping to gain some insight on the characteristic differences between the following two distinct sets [(1) and (2)] of systems of equations. In particular, Gaussian elimination doesn't produce the correct result for the second.

(1)
Gaussian elimination does work for a system of equations like this (Wikipedia example):
2x + y - z = 8
-3x - y + 2z = -11
-2x + y + 2z = -3

However, I have so far been unable to use Gaussian elimination to solve the below example. Context: given 3 coordinates, I want to solve the resulting system of equations to produce a parabola that intersects each point.
Three example (x,y) coordinates: (-1.5, 1) , (-0.4, 1.5) , (0.8, 2.7)

(2)
Resulting system of equations:
1 = a(-1.5)^2 + b(-1.5) + c
1.5 = a(-0.4)^2 + b(-0.4) + c
2.7 = a(0.8)^2 + b(0.8) + c

My gut tells me it has to do with the distinction that occurs as a result of plugging in these values into a quadratic formula template, wherein the unknown values are "not the typical" x, y, and z variables, but instead what I would call the coefficients. My mathematical understanding and vocabulary isn't very deep here; any instruction or explanation would be appreciated.

Thanks so much,
Mike

Comments & criticism welcome - I'm new here.

Comment: I am not sure whether your definition of a parabola is unique. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic
 as you see, you need 5 points to determine a specific conic, but maybe i'm missing the point.
Futhermore please type out your word by word, so we can see what you have done, whether it was correct and where you got stuck.

Welcome to stackexchange and don't take the downvotes personally! :)

Comment: If you want to use the $(x-x_0)(x-x_1)$ template, you'll need to find the specific two points where the parabola intersects the $x$-axis. And plug in those $x_0, x_1$ values.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: "Gaussian elimination doesn't produce the correct result for the second": can you expand ?

Comment: @LordCommander: the OP is obviously after a quadratic function, i.e. a parabola of vertical axis. By the way, a general parabola requires four points only.

Comment: Will update with more detail and clarification as soon as i'm able. Briefly, it's a very niche context and personal project - I am trying to do something akin to functional programming in the online graphing calculator Desmos, for solving systems of equations. It's constrained to say the least. Thanks all!

Comment: @YvesDaoust if it was so obvious to you why didn't you answer his question?

Comment: @LordCommander: because I asked the OP two clarifications, which haven't come yet. Is that a problem for you ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust excuses, should have been 'obvious'

Comment: @LordCommander Apologies, I was just doing my best to be clear as mud. Don'tcha know I'm a strange Minnesotan type. Anyways - thanks y'all for the help. This was the answer I needed - to make sure I was even walking down a valid path here. The offending mistake was a gd missing minus sign, haha. Lord Commander, if you want credit for the answer (the conic page helped) - just copy it on over. Cheers.

Comment: @Mike feel free to mark my answer as the answer if you were satisfied with it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure whether your definition of a parabola is unique.

As you see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Five_points_determine_a_conic#Construction) , you need 5 points to determine a specific conic, but maybe i'm missing the point.

To determine a specific parabola you need [3 points](https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-minimum-number-of-points-needed-to-identify-a-unique-quadratic-function/answer/Vishakh-Rajendran-1).

Futhermore please type out your word by word, so we can see what you have done, whether it was correct and where you got stuck. Welcome to stackexchange and don't take the downvotes personally! :)

If you want to use the $(x−x_0)(x−x_1)$ template, you'll need to find the specific two points where the parabola intersects the $x$-axis. And plug in those $x_0$,$x_1$ values.

Comment: Thanks for the help here. I definitely unknowingly followed very non-standard procedure and question clarity. Thank you for making up the difference. I will consider your comments and suggestions as best I can for future posts. Cheers.